# Command \swdefault already defined

Tags: pdftex, texlive

Just installed `texlive-full` and tried to compile a simple example document that compiles fine on another machine but have been encountering an error.

The error message seems to originate from the file `ifthen.sty` and reads as follows:

> LaTeX Error: Command \swdefault already defined.Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

I tried googling the error but it didn't help.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: Here's a MWE that throws the error on the first machine but not the second.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage{allrunes}

\newunicodechar{ᚠ}{\textarn{f}}
\newunicodechar{ᚢ}{\textarn{u}}
\newunicodechar{ᚦ}{\textarn{\th}}
\newunicodechar{ᚭ}{\textarn{A}}
\newunicodechar{ᚱ}{\textarn{r}}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the simplest document you can make that compiles fine on the other machine but still gives you the error?  If you put `\listfiles` at the top of that file before the `\documentclass`, what version files is that other machine using?

Comment: `\swdefault` is newly added to kernel of LaTeX in its 2020-02-02 release, see [LaTeX2e News Issue 31](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews31.pdf). There is probably some font package you load that also defined `\swdefault`. Providing an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would help others to tracing the problem.

Comment: the package `allrunes` is incompatible with the extended series support of  a current LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by rebuilding `allrunes` from source, and updating the conflicting constant names. You can use my fix by simply copying the .sty from this repo:
https://github.com/viking-sudo-rm/allrunes

Comment: Thank you, it works.