# Creating a page border made of text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a page border that consists of text. I've managed to figure out how to draw the pattern I want with `tikz`, and have been attempting to use decorations in order to achieve this. This works fine with normal text, but I'm attempting to use the `allrunes` package for this border, which fails (LaTeX can't compile that combo).

The image below showcases what I'm trying to get. The fat line with rounded corners shows how the text border should run (the line itself should not be visible). It terminates on the edge of the page on the right side.

Anyone got any suggestions as to what I could try?

[image: Sample page]

**EDIT:**

People have suggested I post what I've tried. The sample below should give some idea what I'm trying to achieve. This only works with regular text. As soon as I try to convert the text to runes using `allrunes` (substitute the text line with `text={\textarc{this is just some sample text that does what I want (not runetext)}}}`), compilation of the document fails.

Any alternatives to get this to work that do not use `tikz` are also welcome. This just seemed like the easy way.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
  rounded corners=25,
  decorate,
  decoration={text along path,raise=2pt,
  text={this is just some sample text that does what I want (not runetext)}}
  ]
  (4,0) --
  (0,0) --
  (0,4) --
  (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post what you tried. (You could try to wrap each special character into `{...}`.)

Comment: I wonder if allrunes uses TikZ.  That would explain the incompatibility.

Comment: Seem that the problem is due to the package `allrunes`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558058/162128) the comment of @Ulrike Fischer

Comment: I've added and MWE, as requested. 

@vi pa: I'm not getting any errors as in the example you linked. The document justy doesn't compile. I've had no trouble with `allrunes` outside the `tikz` environment.

Comment: @Faust Do you have update your distribution recently?